# An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10) in centos7 OPNFV arno image

Tags: ruby

Installing the 'vagrant-centos7_fix' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.10'` succeeds before bundling.
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetcherError: Error::ETIMEOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi-1.9.10.gem)

I tried accesssing following link https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi-1.9.10.gem in windows machine there also I am getting the timeout error:

Can anyone please suggest any altenative to install ffi=1.9.10 component.

Comment: It looks like DNS issue. Can you reach rubygems.org directly via curl/wget or your browser (if it's normal computer)?

Comment: Are you behind some sort of home router or firewall or something? I tried the exact same rubygems server as you, and it connected no problem. It almost looks like your port 443 (https) is being blocked for some reason. Try telnet rubygems.org 443 and see if it connects, if not you're having firewall/router issues.

Comment: Are you by any chance behind a proxy? You could use the -p flag to set the proxy. Try this manually. `sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.10' -p user:pass@proxy.example.com`

Comment: Just an FYI but for those of us having this issue with Vagrant vms on Windows, it seems to have to do with having NFS shares.

Answer (score 25):

I think you are missing ruby dev package. Install it.

apt-get install ruby-dev

Comment: Hi Leo, I tried installing ruby-dev its giving me error: No package available.

Comment: Thats installable.. I tried on my Ubuntu machine.

apt-cache madison ruby-dev
  
ruby-dev |  1:1.9.3.4 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
ruby-defaults |  1:1.9.3.4 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources

Answer (score 2):

Same error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10) in Fedora24. Information at the log file was: **error:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 No that file and directory**.

And then I install `redhat-rpm-config` package use the command:

`sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config`

As the answer told of this question [g++ error:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 No that file and directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624428/g-error-usr-lib-rpm-redhat-redhat-hardened-cc1-no-that-file-and-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error when installing some vagrant server. In my case it was enough to install a newest version of Vagrant again - I had old version on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly similar issue.

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.10'` succeeds before bundling.

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x86-mingw32.gem)

I was trying to run vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager. It would not work. I was using 64-pc-cygwin emulator shell on windows 7. I tried running the command in Git Bash emulator shell and it installed with no issues.