# G++ error:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, fedora

I'm studying qt on platform Fedora linux, It threw a g++ error as below while I make a sample cpp

```
g++ error:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
```

Would who indicate how to do for me please?

Comment: looks like g++ is not installed or not properly installed

Answer (score 139):

You need to install `redhat-rpm-config` which is required by some of the `qt` switches, probably:

```
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config
```

From [AskFedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/61075/mysql_config-cflags-does-not-work-on-fedora-21/).

Comment: I wonder which upstream project this bug should be filed against

Comment: This is not any upstream project fault. The above file is required by build process in Fedora. Either the package which is using this file should depend on `redhat-rpm-config` package directly (`qt`?) or the OP did install QT or other tools somehow different way that he skipped the dependency, but it is hard to guess.

Answer (score 16):

According to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-gate/+bug/1424582) topic installation of the package `redhat-rpm-config` should fix this problem.

> /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 is included in the package redhat-rpm-config. I had a similiar issue on a local development system and installing this package solved the issue for me.