# Compilation error of R package

Tags: r, compiler-errors, fedora, cran

I want to compile [hsphase](https://cran.r-project.org/package=hsphase) package (R package available in CRAN).

I used this command in R `install.packages("hsphase")`.

I have got the following errors:

```
g++ -m64 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -o hsphase.so FastDist.o MAF.o Ohd.o TypeConversion.o block.o block4Phase.o co.o diag.o hsp.o main.o memory.o oh.o swDetect.o [1] 0 -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -fopenmp -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
g++: error: [1]: No such file or directory
g++: error: 0: No such file or directory
/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'hsphase.so' failed
make: *** [hsphase.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘hsphase’
* removing ‘/home/mhf/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/hsphase’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYukJQa/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("hsphase") :
  installation of package ‘hsphase’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am using fedora 24.

The g++ version:
gcc version 6.1.1 20160621 (Red Hat 6.1.1-3) (GCC)

Please check the link flag:
what is this:
`[1] 0`

Comment: The g++ is there. There is a linking error.

Comment: I had a similar issue installing another R package, and later found that some of the dependencies for the required package were missing, try `install.packages("hsphase", dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: You seem to be missing a system-level dependency; lines like this -- `-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld` -- are a good clue. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624428/g-error-usr-lib-rpm-redhat-redhat-hardened-cc1-no-that-file-and-directory).

Comment: This is the content of that file `*self_spec:
+ %{!shared:%{!r:-pie}}

*link:
+ -z now
`

Comment: @ Imran Ali, your comment did not solve the problem.

Comment: It may help to build your R version with that compiler so  that the build calls made by R match it.  In any event, this has nothing to do with Rcpp so I'll remove that tag,

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel, I build the R but still I cannot compile the package.

Comment: You may need the help of the `r-sig-fedora` list.  It is not `gcc-6` per se which we use on Debian too.

Comment: I have the same problem with "clang++".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comment this line in the scr/Makevars file:

```
#PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

Now, I can compile the package.