# GCC error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip, fedora

```
[axaysd@localhost ~]$ sudo pip install lightfm
[sudo] password for axaysd: 
Collecting lightfm
  Using cached lightfm-1.12.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from lightfm)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from lightfm)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from lightfm)
Installing collected packages: lightfm

Running setup.py install for lightfm ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-08iD5u/lightfm/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-T0wh6x-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
copying lightfm/_lightfm_fast.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
copying lightfm/evaluation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
copying lightfm/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
copying lightfm/lightfm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm/datasets
copying lightfm/datasets/movielens.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm/datasets
copying lightfm/datasets/stackexchange.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm/datasets
copying lightfm/datasets/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm/datasets
copying lightfm/datasets/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm/datasets
copying lightfm/_lightfm_fast_no_openmp.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
copying lightfm/_lightfm_fast_openmp.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
running build_ext
building 'lightfm._lightfm_fast_openmp' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lightfm
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security
-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches
-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC
-fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4
-grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic
-D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lightfm/_lightfm_fast_openmp.c
-o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
**gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-08iD5u/lightfm/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-T0wh6x-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-08iD5u/lightfm/**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [g++ error:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 No that file and directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624428/g-error-usr-lib-rpm-redhat-redhat-hardened-cc1-no-that-file-and-directory)

Answer (score 27):

On Fedora 24, this worked for me:

```
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-gate/+bug/1424582

Answer (score 7):

'**dnf provides *filename***' (or 'yum provides *filename*') can usually tell you what packages provide the file that is being complained about:

```
root@nuc:~/ > dnf provides '/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1'
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:28 ago on Sat 28 Oct 2017 12:53:33 PM EDT.
redhat-rpm-config-63-1.fc26.noarch : Red Hat specific rpm configuration files
Repo        : @System

redhat-rpm-config-63-1.fc26.noarch : Red Hat specific rpm configuration files
Repo        : fedora
```

The above response of 'redhat-rpm-config-63-1.fc26.noarch' confirms that Trần's answer is correct. The "provides" command will save your butt more often than you can imagine!