# Can't install Twisted for Python3 on Fedora for some reason

Tags: python, linux, twisted, fedora

For some reason, I just can't get it to work. After running `pip3 install twisted`, here is the error that I'm presented with: https://bpaste.net/show/3b73706ea448 Along with `error: command 'gcc failed with exit status 1`, it also said `Failed building wheel for twisted` at some point. I've tried `sudo yum install python3-devel` and I also have gcc installed already. The same error occurs, whether I'm in a virtualenv or not.

Comment: Don't post crucial details to third-party websites and then link to them here.  The details tend to vanish, as they have done in this case.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Ah, sorry. It should be noted, though, that all the errors I received are described in the description. What was in the link were mostly the installation details that `pip install` provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using the following:

`sudo yum install redhat-rpm-config`

as seen here: [G++ error:/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624428/g-error-usr-lib-rpm-redhat-redhat-hardened-cc1-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You might need sudo for that installation.
Try something along the lines of:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install twisted
```

It's common for me at least that I need sudo for the correct installation of python packages (especially when compilation is involved)

(Unfortunately I can't comment to your post so I posted it as an answer)